# How to add customized ticks in Heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I plotted an array in seaborn heatmap, and I want to add tick limits to the axis.

My code:

```
# plot
eixoz = numpy.linspace(0, Z)
eixor = numpy.linspace(ra, R, nr)
eixox = D
numpy.meshgrid(eixoz, eixor)
ax = seaborn.heatmap(eixox)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.xlabel("Eixo z",  fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("Eixo r", fontsize=20)
ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
ax.collections[0].colorbar.set_label("Celsius", fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

How can I add those limit ticks in blue? And also, how can I resize the color bar numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the colorbar tick labels can be changed via `ax.collections[0].colorbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)`.

Text at the start and end of the axes can be place using the [`axes` transform](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html), where 0 is the left (or bottom) and 1 is the right (or top) of the axes. Negative values (or values larger than 1) are proportionall outside the axes area. Horizontal and vertical lines can use the same transform, but unlike text need `clip_on=False` to be drawn outside the axes area.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
len_eixoz = 20
eixox = np.repeat(np.arange(37.55, 37.66, 0.02), len_eixoz).reshape(-1, len_eixoz)
ax = sns.heatmap(eixox)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_xlabel("Eixo z", fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel("Eixo r", fontsize=20)
ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
ax.collections[0].colorbar.set_label("Celsius", fontsize=20)
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)

x0, x1 = 1, 2
y0, y1 = 0, 1
ax.text(0, -0.07, x0, ha='center', va='top', fontsize=20, color='steelblue', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(1, -0.07, x1, ha='center', va='top', fontsize=20, color='steelblue', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(-0.05, 0, y0, ha='right', va='center', fontsize=20, color='steelblue', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(-0.05, 1, y1, ha='right', va='center', fontsize=20, color='steelblue', transform=ax.transAxes)

ax.vlines([0, 1], [0, 0], [-0.06, -0.06], color='crimson', clip_on=False, transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.hlines([0, 1], [0, 0], [-0.04, -0.04], color='crimson', clip_on=False, transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Note that calling `sns.set(font_scale=1.8)` at the start would scale all fonts.